# Building external JS (not TS) files in Angular Library with ng build?

Tags: angular-cli, angular-library

I built an Angular component library using the Angular CLI (for libraries), and one of my components is importing and using a local JS file. However, when I "ng build", only the TS files are bundled into the Dist folder. How do I also allow the build to include JS files?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add custom JavaScript file in your application then copy or create your own js file in src/assets. Found in this folder dir "src/assets/js" e.g custom.js

```
$(function() {
    alert('Hello, custom js');
});
```

And add this JavaScript file in scripts array in angular.

```
"scripts": [
  .....
  "src/assets/js/custom.js"
]
```